# How to perform clustering on data with time variant and time invariant attributes, in R?

Tags: r, time-series, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

The data looks something like the example table below. I am using R to do the clustering.

TIV: Time invariant data
TV: Time variant data

location | population | TIV2 | Q1_TV1 | Q2_TV1 | Q3_TV1 | Q4_TV1 | Q1_TV2 | Q2_TV2 | Q3_TV2
A ..........|............. 30 |..... 9 |.......... 25 |......... 35 |.......... 22 |......... 15 |......... 20 |.......... 30 |......... 10
B ..........|............. 35 |..... 7 |.......... 38 |......... 13 |.......... 35 |......... 17 |......... 23 |.......... 34 |........... 8
C ..........|............. 32 |..... 5 |.......... 24 |......... 39 |.......... 21 |......... 19 |......... 23 |.......... 27 |......... 13

I have a dataset with unique locations for every row (location), a few variables whose values remain constant over time (population, TIV2) and a few variables whose values change quarterly (Q1_TV1 - Q4_TV1 and Q1_TV2 - Q4_TV2, etc.).

I want to cluster the data to find similar locations using the time invariant and time variant data. I am aware there are packages for clustering time series data, such as TSclust. However, I am not sure if TSclust will create a distance matrix with both types of data included.

I may have the wrong approach entirely to cluster the data I have.

Comment: Yes, distance matrix includes all columns. Think it as each row corresponds to a different observation, and column values represent features for each observation. Your distance matrix has dimensions of # of rows X # of rows

Comment: Thanks for the response Haroon, but I am still a bit confused. I think you've explained what the distance matrix is, but I am still unsure of of how to cluster my data accounting for both types of data (time varying and not varying) in the same clustering analysis. I've looked more into the TSclust package and the example datasets are all time varying attributes only, not a mixture.

Comment: Consider TIV's as constants. Before clustering scale all your columns so that a particular data column won't dominate others. Another thing I can suggest is to take a small slice of your entire data and then visualise the clustering results with and without TIV's. I am sure that you will decide which approach represents your cluster very well.